# How to install ROS packages in Windows

Tags: windows, ros

I am very new to ROS and currently following the document that the official page has. As I said in the title I am using ROS on Windows. In one of the examples, it uses "apt" to install packages but apt is for Linux-based systems. I was wondering how can I download packages on Windows (for example rqt_graph).

I tried to download it using chocolaty but the rqt_graph package does not exist.